# strange "error: expected ‘)’ before ‘;’ token" but I can't find it

Tags: c++

```
YAxis::YAxis() {
    TextWriter *tw = new MBTextWriter;
    Create(Y_AXIS_WIDTH, Y_AXIS_HEIGHT);
    SetPosition(Y_AXIS_STARTING_X, Y_AXIS_STARTING_Y);
    SetFocus();
    SetColor(114, 114, 114);
    for (unsigned int y = 0; y < Y_AXIS_HEIGHT / GRID_CELL_HEIGHT; y++) {
        if (y >= 10)
            tw->SetPosition(8, y * GRID_CELL_HEIGHT + 14);
        else
            tw->SetPosition(8, y * GRID_CELL_HEIGHT + 9);
        tw->SetMessage(toString(y));
        tw->Write(); 
    }
}
```

This error seems to be centered around this constructor but I can't see it.
Any help would be appreciated.

Full error here:

```
Editor/YAxis.cpp: In constructor ‘YAxis::YAxis()’:
Editor/YAxis.cpp:6:33: error: expected ‘)’ before ‘;’ token
Editor/YAxis.cpp:6:50: error: expected primary-expression before ‘)’ token
Editor/YAxis.cpp:6:50: error: expected ‘;’ before ‘)’ token
```

Let me know if you need more information on what I am trying to accomplish with this code.

Comment: 1. Send code here and not in another site. 2. How can we know what is line 6?

Comment: You can start by including the `YAxis` constructor in your question (please do not add links) including some context (like thelines before it), and possibly relevant parts of the class definition (preferably a portion of the header file). And check that you're not missing a semicolon in a header file.

Comment: Please put the code on here instead of in a paste bin, and mark the line where the error occurs (I'm not convinved that line 6 of the error message corresponds to line 6 in your pastebin). Also, are any of the names used in your function `#define` macros?

Comment: You probably have a typo elsewhere

Comment: Which line is line 6? What comes *before* that line? Have you checked all header files, so there is no missing semicolon in any of them? You might want to read [the Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/156810/stack-overflow-question-checklist), it will help you write better questions.

Comment: The answer lies in the code that you did not show us. You didn't tell us which is line 6. And you did not show the macros. Do you try to debug your own programs without looking at the code? -1

Answer (score 2):

If the line #6 is this one:

```
for (unsigned int y = 0; y < Y_AXIS_HEIGHT / GRID_CELL_HEIGHT; y++) {
```

the problem could come in the definition of the macros:

- Y_AXIS_HEIGHT
- GRID_CELL_HEIGHT

Could you provide their contents?

Comment: I'll bet that they wrote `#define Y_AXIS_HEIGHT 42;`. But you are probably thinking of that.